# XSL - Embedded Lookup Table - Lookup Value of Variable

Tags: xml, xslt, lookup, lookup-tables

StackExchange, I'm hoping someone here can help me with this issue!

I'm working in **XSLT 1.0**, trying to embed a lookup table to convert some unformatted data to a standardized, formatted structure.

I have read and searched and tried various methods to accomplish this and none of them have been able to generate a result. (Though I'm not getting any errors, either.)

Below is a sample of the XSL I'm working with:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:lookup="lookup" exclude-result-prefixes="lookup">

<xsl:key name="lookup_table" match="lookup:table/row" use="@raw"/>

<lookup:table>
    <row raw="raw1" corrected="Raw One"/>
    <row raw="raw2" corrected="Raw Two"/>
    <row raw="raw3" corrected="Raw Three"/>
    <row raw="raw4" corrected="Raw Four"/>
    <row raw="raw5" corrected="Raw Five"/>
</lookup:table>

<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:variable name="lookup_table" select='document("")//lookup:table/row'/>
<xsl:variable name="value_to_lookup" select="'raw1'"/>

        <!-- In the actual XSL document, this variable would use an XPath to point to another attribute. -->
        <!-- In this case, the value of this variable must be changed manually. -->

<xsl:value-of select='document("")//lookup:table/row[@raw = $value_to_lookup]/@corrected'/>

<xsl:value-of select='document("")//lookup:table[@raw = $value_to_lookup]/@corrected'/>

<xsl:value-of select='$lookup_table[@raw = $value_to_lookup]/@corrected'/>

<xsl:value-of select="key('lookup_table',$value_to_lookup)/@corrected"/>

    <!-- The above lines are the various methods I've seen documented on other websites that claim these methods should allow me to what I need to. -->
    <!-- There is no need to have multiple identical results, I only have multiple attempts here to document the steps I have tried. -->

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The current output of this code is nothing (literally).

*The desired output when the variable `value_to_lookup` is equal to "raw1" is:*

```
Raw One
```

*For further clarification, the desired output when the variable `value_to_lookup` is equal to "raw4" is:*

```
Raw Four
```

The output of this bit of code will be stored in a variable and called later when needed.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***-- edited in response to changes in the question --***

Looking at the 4 options presented in your stylesheet:

1. This works as expected:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select='document("")//lookup:table/row[@raw = $value_to_lookup]/@corrected'/>
   ```
2. This cannot work, because `raw` is an attribute of `row`, and `row`
   is absent from the path:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select='document("")//lookup:table[@raw = $value_to_lookup]/@corrected'/>
   ```
3. This works as expected:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select='$lookup_table[@raw = $value_to_lookup]/@corrected'/>
   ```
4. This doesn't work because in XSLT 1.0, keys only work in the context
   of current document:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="key('lookup_table',$value_to_lookup)/@corrected"/>
   ```

   To make it work, you would do:

   ```
   <xsl:for-each select="document('')">
       <xsl:value-of select="key('lookup_table',$value_to_lookup)/@corrected"/>
   </xsl:for-each>
   ```

---

***-- added in response to the following clarifications in comments --***

> The XSL stylesheet is part of the application. When I want to generate
>   a new resultant document or make changes to an existing one, I go
>   through the menus of the Java-based application. I eventually arrive
>   at a screen with a small menu on the side and large text-entry window
>   in the middle. This text-entry window is where the XSL coding is
>   typed.

---

> what do you get as the result of `<xsl:value-of select="count(document(''))"/>`?

---

> The result is "0".

Apparently, your processing environment does not support using the `document()` function to refer to the stylesheet itself. This means you will need to use another method to perform an internal lookup - namely, define a variable and convert it into a node-set - as was already suggested in the answer by MiMo.

*Note that this has nothing to do with Java. Practically all XSLT 1.0 processors support the EXSLT `node-set()` extension function, but some Microsoft processors recognize it only in their own namespace.*

---

For completion, here's how you would use a key to lookup a value from the variable:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="value_to_lookup" select="'raw1'"/>

<xsl:key name="lookup" match="row" use="@raw"/>

<xsl:variable name="lookup">
    <row raw="raw1" corrected="Raw One"/>
    <row raw="raw2" corrected="Raw Two"/>
    <row raw="raw3" corrected="Raw Three"/>
    <row raw="raw4" corrected="Raw Four"/>
    <row raw="raw5" corrected="Raw Five"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="lookup-set" select="exsl:node-set($lookup)" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- change context to the lookup "document" -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$lookup-set">
        <xsl:value-of select="key('lookup', $value_to_lookup)/@corrected"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, you're correct about that. Trivial changes.

I have implemented them, as well as copied your code exactly as is above, yet your code is still not producing any output.

The problem appears to be associated with `document('')`. As a test, if I type `<xsl:value-of select="$value_to_lookup"/>` within the `document('')` tags, I get no output at all. However, when typed outside of the tags, I can at least see that `$value_to_lookup` is indeed set to "raw1". Suggestions?

Comment: Michael, I tried it in the actual production XSL document. Anything that was placed inside the `<xsl:for-each select="document('')">` tags would not generate a result. I called some of my known-good variables inside the tags using `xsl:value-of` statements to test, and they showed nothing either. Additionally, the variables you came up with, when called outside of those tags, showed the correct stored values. This is what leads me to believe that the `<xsl:for-each select="document('')">` code is the issue.

Comment: Right, and I believe that is being done via a Java-based application.

The XSL stylesheet is part of the application. When I want to generate a new resultant document or make changes to an existing one, I go through the menus of the Java-based application. I eventually arrive at a screen with a small menu on the side and large text-entry window in the middle. This text-entry window is where the XSL coding is typed. The resultant documents apply the selected XSL to the specific XML being worked on at the time and then generate an HTML-based output document. Does that help answer the question?

Comment: Michael, using `<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')" />`, I retrieved "Apache Software Foundation." Does that help?

Comment: Michael, your updated solution is working! Thank you for your help and patience, as well as your thorough answers. They are very much appreciated.

In terms of speed/performance and reliability, is either answer a better choice, or is it simply a preference as to which to use?

Comment: In general, using key should be faster, because the processor will pre-index the lookup table - but I would test this in your specific situation before making a judgement.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `<xsl:variable name="value_to_lookup" select='raw1'/>` sets `value_to_lookup` to the value of a (non existent) `raw1` element - so it is empty.

What you want is `<xsl:variable name="value_to_lookup" select="'raw1'"/>` and then `<xsl:value-of select='document("")//lookup:table/row[@raw = $value_to_lookup]/@corrected'/>` works. Complete XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
            xmlns:lookup="lookup" exclude-result-prefixes="lookup">

<lookup:table>
    <row raw="raw1" corrected="Raw One"/>
    <row raw="raw2" corrected="Raw Two"/>
    <row raw="raw3" corrected="Raw Three"/>
    <row raw="raw4" corrected="Raw Four"/>
    <row raw="raw5" corrected="Raw Five"/>
</lookup:table>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="value_to_lookup" select="'raw1'"/>
    <xsl:value-of select='document("")//lookup:table/row[@raw = $value_to_lookup]/@corrected'/>
</xsl:template>
```

You can define the lookup table without using `document()` doing something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="lookup_table_fragment">
    <row raw="raw1" corrected="Raw One"/>
    <row raw="raw2" corrected="Raw Two"/>
    <row raw="raw3" corrected="Raw Three"/>
    <row raw="raw4" corrected="Raw Four"/>
    <row raw="raw5" corrected="Raw Five"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="lookup_table" select="msxsl:node-set($lookup_table_fragment)" />
```

and then:

```
<xsl:value-of select='$lookup_table/row[@raw = $value_to_lookup]/@corrected'/>
```

(`msxsl:node-set` is Microsoft-specific, but all processors have a function to convert a fragment to a node set)

This last version adapted for A Java XSLT processor reads:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
        xmlns:lookup="lookup" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="lookup exsl">

    <xsl:variable name="lookup_table_fragment">
        <row raw="raw1" corrected="Raw One"/>
        <row raw="raw2" corrected="Raw Two"/>
        <row raw="raw3" corrected="Raw Three"/>
        <row raw="raw4" corrected="Raw Four"/>
        <row raw="raw5" corrected="Raw Five"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="lookup_table" select="exsl:node-set($lookup_table_fragment)" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="value_to_lookup" select="'raw1'"/>
        <xsl:value-of select='$lookup_table/row[@raw = $value_to_lookup]/@corrected'/>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and can be tested at http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation

Comment: Okay, this has solved part of the issue. The variable is now defined correctly as "raw1," however, the final output of "Raw One" is not displayed.

Comment: I added to the answer the complete XSLT that I used to test - and it works for me - the output is just the string `Raw One`

Comment: Neither of your methods appear to be working. In fact, the alternate method, using variables only, crashes the output sheet. (It shows only whitespace, no other content - even content that was present/working before.) Suggestions?

Comment: ...maybe `document()` does not work in your XSLT processor? The second version uses a Microsoft specific function, so if you don't have that (and don't define its namespace) it won't work. I added a version of the second example using Java extensions and a URL where it can be tested.

Comment: The namespace "msxsl" was declared in the actual XML document as `xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"`, so perhaps you're on to something about the processor being the limitation. I will experiment with the Java-based version.

Comment: Great news! The Java-based version is working great! For future reference, is there anything you can discern about the processor's limitations from this? Such information could come in handy in the future...

Comment: Which processor were you using? I guess it did not like `document("")`

Comment: I discovered, with some help from Michael in his answer, that the processor is the Apache Xalan processor and that `document()` will not work for it as the result of `<xsl:value-of select="count(document(''))"/>` is "0".

Comment: Used this to answer my own similar question here:.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59415629/how-to-do-a-code-table-lookup-in-xslt-1-0/59416009#59416009.  I just added a param to the template call.